# Adding a SQL Server database with the same name SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have the following:

DB1 - Live DB QMLive.mdf / OMLive.ldf - Currently Running

DB2 - QMLive.mdf / OMLive.ldf (3 Days Prior from a Backup)

I need to Attach DB 2 as MonthEnd.mdf / MonthEnd.ldf as I do not have a .bak file (had issues with SQL Network Auth on a NAS)

When I rename DB2 Files and try to attach it, I get an error that I can't mount it... I guess the DB2 has the same Name as DB1 stored in a Table or something.

Comment: `try to attach it` how? What is the exact error?  Are you using some point-and-click UI? Can't you put a different database name in the dialog?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You state that for DB2, you have a backup ("3 Days Prior from a Backup") but then you state "...as I do not have a .bak file..."

Comment: The backup is from a Snapshot of the whole PC and mounting the Image I retrieved the 2 files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following example I created a MyDB (MyDB.mdf + MyDB_log.ldf) Database.
Then I made a copy of these files: MyDB-2.mdf + MyDB-2_log.ldf

I then attached the "-2" files as "MyDB-2" database to SQL Server using this procedure:

1. Right click on "Database" and select "Attach..."
2. Add the "MyDB-2.mdf" using the "Add..." button
3. Manually edit the highlighed sections adding "-2" to "Attach as" and "Current File Path"

[image]

This way both databases are attached:

[image]

Comment: you're a champ. This solved the issue..